# How can I use update statement with LEFT JOIN in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have this query in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE 
  result 
SET 
  result.IndxRent = idx.IndxRent 
FROM 
  #resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay AS result
  LEFT JOIN @TableIndxRent AS idx ON result.IndxId = idx.IndxId 
  AND result.ActiveDate = idx.IndxDate;
```

I need the same in PostgreSQL, but it's updating all the rows with the same value (NULL).

Using a friend's suggestion from here, doesn't work:

```
UPDATE resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay result
    SET IndxRent = (SELECT idx.IndxRent
                    TableIndxRent idx 
                    WHERE result.IndxId = idx.IndxId AND
                          result.ActiveDate = idx.IndxDate
                   );
```

Another user, told me to add the WHERE clause, so I tried:

```
UPDATE resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay result
    SET IndxRent = (SELECT idx.IndxRent
                    TableIndxRent idx 
                    WHERE result.IndxId = idx.IndxId AND
                          result.ActiveDate = idx.IndxDate
                   )
where result.IndxId = idx.IndxId;
```

But doens't work either...

I've already tried so many things, but seems like I'm missing something...

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `IndxId` is a key on the table to be updated, something like this should work:

```
with newvals as (
  select result.IndxId, idx.IndxRent
    from resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay result
         left join TableIndxRent idx
                on idx.IndxId = result.IndxId
               and idx.IndxDate = result.ActiveDate
)
update resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay
   set IndxRent = n.IndxRent
  from newvals n
 where n.IndxId = resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay.IndxId
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the subquery solution wouldn't work:

```
UPDATE resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay r
SET IndxRent = (
    SELECT i.IndxRent
    FROM TableIndxRent i 
    WHERE r.IndxId = i.IndxId AND r.ActiveDate = i.IndxDate
);
```

That's really the same logic as the original query with the `left join`. If there is a match in source table `TableIndxRent`, then the target table column is updated to the value of `IndxRent` - otherwise is is et to `null`.

I am often suspicious about `left join`s on `update`s. Do you really want to set to `null` rows that have no match in the source table? If not, then the update/(inner) join syntax is a better fit for your use case:

```
UPDATE resultRcPositionActiveBenchDay r
SET IndxRent = i.IndxRent
FROM TableIndxRent i
WHERE r.IndxId = i.IndxId AND r.ActiveDate = i.IndxDate
```

Note that Postgres does not want the target table in the `from` clause (it should appear in the `update` clause only).

Comment: In SQL Server I can use a "select * from..." in the middle of a stored procedure. How can I do something to help me "debug" the function?